# Prevent Javascript from redirecting

Tags: javascript, curl

I'm using PHP with CURL to include a part of a other website in my page. Now the included part contains a peace of JavaScript code that redirect the page to ./framebuster. Which will 404 cause that page is not located on my server.

Is there a way to run a JavaScript code to prevent it going to ./framebuster? without disabling JavaScript all together?

Comment: well you could always just manipulate the code returned by CURL as a string, searching for and removing/replacing the offending code

Comment: also, I have no idea what you're attempting, but make sure there are no legal or ethical problems with what you're trying to do. You can't/shouldn't just import other poeple's content into your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it loaded into an iframe?

You can try breaking the control of their Javascript with `sandbox="allow-same-origin"` like so:

```
<iframe id="iframeOtherSite" src="http://www.othersite.com/" sandbox="allow-same-origin"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `onbeforeunload` property with `window.frames[0].stop()`  to stop iframe from load the buggy script !

if you want more about `onbeforeunload` [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload)